# How can i make this curly design in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-design, flutter-custompainter

[image]

Does any one know how you can make this in flutter? I used to custom painter and i got the curles but i was not able to add the color like the one in picture.
I was wondering maybe if there was a correct way to make this. If not is there anyother way you know of making this design??